# Extracting latest values in a Dask dataframe with non-unique index column dates

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm quite familiar with pandas dataframes but I'm very new to Dask so I'm still trying to wrap my head around parallelizing my code.
I've obtained my desired results using pandas and pandarallel already so what I'm trying to figure out is if I can scale up the task or speed it up somehow using Dask.

Let's say my dataframe has datetimes as non-unique indices, a values column and an id column.

```
time                        value   id
2021-01-01 00:00:00.210281  28.08   293707
2021-01-01 00:00:00.279228  28.07   293708
2021-01-01 00:00:00.697341  28.08   293709
2021-01-01 00:00:00.941704  28.08   293710
2021-01-01 00:00:00.945422  28.07   293711
...     ...     ...
2021-01-01 23:59:59.288914  29.84   512665
2021-01-01 23:59:59.288914  29.83   512666
2021-01-01 23:59:59.288914  29.82   512667
2021-01-01 23:59:59.525227  29.84   512668
2021-01-01 23:59:59.784754  29.84   512669
```

What I want to extract is the latest value for every second. e.g. if the price right before `2021-01-01 00:00:01` is the row with the index of `2021-01-01 00:00:00.945422` the latest value is `28.07`.

In my case, sometimes index values are not unique so as a tie breaker, I'd like to use the `id` column. The value with the largest `id` number will be considered the latest value. For the case of the three values tied at the time `2021-01-01 23:59:59.288914`, the value `29.82` would be chosen since the largest `id` for that date would be `512667`. Also note that `id` is not consistent throughout the dataset and I cannot only rely on it for ordering my data.

In pandas I simply do this by obtaining the last index

```
last_index = df.loc[date_minus60: date_curr].index[-1]
last_values = df.loc[last_index]
```

and then if the value of `last_values.index.is_unique` is false, I finally perform `last_values.sort_values('id').iloc[-1]`.

I've been having a hard time translating this code to Dask encountering issues regarding my delayed function resulting to them to need computing before I can reindex my dataframe again.

I'd like to know if there are any best practices to dealing with this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below shows that it's a very similar syntax:

```py
import dask

# generate dask dataframe
ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries(freq="500ms", partition_freq="1h")

# generate a pandas dataframe
df = ddf.partitions[0].compute()  # pandas df for example

# sample dates
date_minus60 = "2000-01-01 00:00:00.000"
date_curr = "2000-01-01 00:00:02.000"

# pandas code
last_index_pandas = df.loc[date_minus60:date_curr].index[-1]
last_values_pandas = df.loc[last_index_pandas]

# dask code
last_index_dask = ddf.loc[date_minus60:date_curr].compute().index[-1]
last_values_dask = ddf.loc[last_index_dask].compute()

# check equality of the results
print(last_values_pandas == last_values_dask)
```

Note that the distinction is in two `.compute` steps in `dask` version, since two lazy values need to be computed: first is to find out the correct index location and second is to get the actual value. Also this assumes that the data is already indexed by the timestamp, if it is not, it's best to index the data before loading into `dask` since `.set_index` is in general a slow operation.

However, depending on what you are really after this is probably not a great use of `dask`. If the underlying idea is to do fast lookups, then a better solution is to use indexed databases (including specialised time-series databases).

Finally, the snippet above is using unique index. If the actual data has non-unique indexes, then the requirement on selection by largest `id` is something that should be handled once the `last_values_dask` is computed, by using something like this (pseudo code, not expected to work right away):

```py
def get_largest_id(last_values):
    return last_values.sort_values('id').tail(1)

last_values_dask = get_largest_id(last_values_dask)
```

There is scope for designing a better pipeline if the lookup is for batches (rather than specific sample dates).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the double `.compute` step! I originally tried that and the results were very slow and inefficient. So it seems like it's best to offload this logic to some other part of the pipeline.
I made the logic work with years worth of data with only CSVs and `pandas` so right now it seems like either I have to add preprocessing before using `dask` or to not use `dask` at all.

Comment: If you have implemented a logic with pandas, then it might be possible to use `dask.delayed` for improving efficiency, but not sure without seeing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

`@Kafkaesque` here's another approach to consider using [`map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html), which maps a custom function across each partition, treating each as a Pandas DataFrame. Generally, it's advisable to use `dask.dataframe` methods directly. In this case, however, `dask.DataFrame.sort_values` only supports sorting by a single column, so `map_partitions` is a good alternative. You may also find [these Dask Groupby examples](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html) helpful.

It's worth noting that using `map_partitions` + `groupby` only works if your dataset is already sorted, such that the same seconds are in the same partition. The example below is for the case where the data are not sorted:

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# example dataset, use sample() to "unsort"
ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries(
    freq="250ms", partition_freq="5d", seed=42
).sample(frac=0.9, replace=True, random_state=42)

# first set the rounded timestamp as the index before calling map_partitions
# (don't need to reset the index if your dataset is already sorted)
ddf = ddf.reset_index()
ddf = ddf.assign(round_timestamp=ddf['timestamp'].dt.floor('S')).set_index('round_timestamp')

def custom_func(df):
    return (
        df
        .sort_values(by=['timestamp', 'id'])
        .groupby('round_timestamp')
        .last()
    )

new_ddf = ddf.map_partitions(custom_func)

# shows embarrassingly parallel execution of 'custom_func' across each partition
new_ddf.visualize(optimize_graph=True)

# check the result of the first partition
new_ddf.partitions[0].compute()
```